Is it possible/recommended to paint the side of piano's keys?
I see that many pianos' keys are kept unpainted. Is there a reason for that? Can it cause any issues to paint the side of piano's keys? (the natural wood that can be seen on the attached picture)


What benefit would you hope to realize by painting the sides of the keys?

@phoog - just for their appearance.

Who's looking at the side of those keys? Seems a totally pointless consideration.

@Tim not totally pointless, perhaps, but certainly fairly subtle.  A bright fluorescent color could be interesting.

You went so far and yet you didn't ask the interesting question: Can we shove tf out of RGB leds in the entire piano?!

@Tim People do. The unpainted sides give a visual contrast when adjacent keys are played, so I think it makes the performance more dynamic looking. Look for videos online and compare it to somebody playing a cheap keyboard with one-piece plastic keys.

It's certainly possible.  Whether it's a good idea depends on your goals.  This answer assumes that the primary goal is to maintain the piano in optimum playing condition, in which case it is not a good idea:

the paint will change the weight of the keys, which will change the balance, touch, and playability of the instrument, which is designed for unpainted keys.
there is very little clearance between the keys, so there is a good chance that the paint will cause the keys to bind to one another, which will make the instrument essentially unplayable.

In a comment, you mention that the purpose of doing this is to alter the appearance of the keys.  Depending on your budget, there are some options that would have a somewhat lower risk than paint.
The best option, of course, if you are prepared to spend a lot of money, is to approach a piano manufacturer with a custom order.  Their engineers and designers might be able to accommodate you.  This approach might also be possible if you are a prominent artist.  See for example the Chihuly Olympia a Steinway with unconventionally colored keys (at least on their exposed surfaces -- peach naturals and yellow sharps).
If a custom order is not possible, and you are willing to accept some risk, the options would depend on the color you seek.  A thin stain or dye would be preferable to paint as it would add less mass and less width to the keys.  If you want a dark color, you might consider some sort of ink.
Other things to consider as ways of reducing the risk include experimenting on a damaged instrument that isn't worth repairing and consulting a professional technician for advice.

Maybe I'm dead wrong with that, but my intuition would be that the keys are colored BEFORE the piano is assembled. So once you have the whole thing before you you should really think twice if it's worth adding a layer of sticky material that could glue the keys together and ruin the instrument.

@haxor789 indeed, this is the main why a custom order from a manufacturer would be best.  They can stain the wood before assembling the instrument (and obtain colored plastic for covering the keys if that is desired, as with the Chihuly Olympia). If I were going to do it after market, though, I would definitely remove the keys and treat them individually rather than trying to do anything with them in place, as noted in Doktor Mayhem's answer.

It is not recommended to paint the sides. The main problem would be that a layer of paint could cause friction/stickiness, preventing the keys returning correctly.
The top itself is artificial ivory or acrylic - not paint - and the entire key is weighted appropriately for the movement. The addition of paint may change the weighting - depending on the paint, of course.
Also, you'd have to disassemble and remove all the keys in order to paint them - which increases the risk of something going wrong during that process.

If you must, I suggest stain rather than paint,.

Not enough rep to comment
You should either have a professional piano tech do this OR be extremely careful because if the paint were still wet when you put the keys back in (im just assuming that's how piano's work im more of a keyboard guy) they could get stuck together and possibly drip into the bottom of the keys.

Yes.  It doesn't take much mechanical skill to remove the keyboard and the keys, but if one is in doubt about one's ability, a piano technician is a good idea (and may be able to offer additional tips about risks, effect on the action, etc.).  The keys should definitely be treated individually and allowed to dry thoroughly before reassembly.
